# From excel find rows with same substring in a column

Tags: excel

I need to find rows with common substring in column.

Say, if I have one row has this data (I used `:` to distinguish column)

```
Row1 : AB : ABC, BCD, ACD
Row2 : BC : ACD, DEF
Row3 : CD : ABC, DBC
Row4 : DE : BCD, DEF
```

So I want a query / script which can show me:

ABC is in:

```
Row1
Row3
```

BCD is in:

```
Row1
Row4
```

ACD is in:

```
Row1
Row2
```

Comment: To return the addresses where the substring happen, you need to use VBA. Are you familiar with VBA, and if so, have you tried anything?

Comment: Use a filter on column B with wildcarded criteria.

Answer (score 0):

With layout as shown, put

```
=IFERROR(FIND(D$1,$C2)>0,"")
```

in D2 and copy across and down.